# fetch coredata in tableview cell (swift4)

Tags: string, uitableview, core-data, tableview, fetch

The code below the calls a coredata and prints the string in a label.

```
@IBOutlet var displayL: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    user = coreDataHandler.getSortedData()
    for i in user! {
        displayL.text = String("\(displayL.text ?? "")\nCourse: \(i.username!) Score: \(i.password!)")

    }}
```

This works and I want to transfer it to a tableview cell but what I have now is not working. Nothing is even showing up in the tableview. My tableview code is below. I just want to take the uitableview cell and have it display a entry for every cell.

```
     import UIKit
import CoreData


class allScoresViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet var tazbleView : UITableView!
var itemsName : [NSManagedObject] = []
var textFieldz : UITextField!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsName.count
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let FetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "User")


    do {
        itemsName = try context.fetch(FetchRequest)
    }catch {
        print("Ashley Tisdale")
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext
        context.delete(itemsName[indexPath.row])
        itemsName.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        do {
            try context.save()
        }
        catch {
            print("Jessica Alba")
        }
        self.tazbleView.reloadData()


    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for : indexPath)

    let user = itemsName[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = ("\nCourse: \(user.username!) Score: \(user.password!)")

    return cell

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that since you fetch your User entities in `viewDidAppear`, that is what you want to use and not `coreDataHandle.getSortedData()`.

Change the declaration of `itemsName` to

```
var itemsName: [User] = []
```

and in `tableView:cellForRowAt:`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for : indexPath)

    let user = itemsName[indexPath.row] 
    cell.textLabel?.text = ("\nCourse: \(user.username!) Score: \(user.password!)")

    return cell
}
```

*Update*

You probably also want to update your declaration of the fetch request property in `viewDidAppear`

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<User>()
```

Comment: I edited my code with your suggestions above. However I am still getting this error Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'username'. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you change the array, itemsName, to be of type User?